# Equivalent mass enhanced inside dielectric medium?

Tags: special-relativity, photons, mass-energy, dielectric

Imagine a [box](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_27.html#Ch27-S6) of mass $M$ and length $L$ containing a medium with refractive index $n$.
A photon is emitted from the left-hand side of the box and is absorbed on the right-hand side.

[image: Photon in box]

Let us assume there is a mass $m \ll M$ associated with the photon which moves a distance $L$.

Assuming the center of gravity of the system does not change then the box moves a distance $x \ll L$ such that:

$$Mx = m L.\tag{1}$$

Now the photon is emitted with momentum $\mathbf{p}$ and the box recoils with momentum $-\mathbf{p}$. The recoil velocity $v$ of the box is

$$v=\frac{p}{M}.\tag{2}$$

The box moves with a velocity $v$ until the photon is absorbed by the right-hand wall and cancels the recoil momentum given to the box when it was emitted.

The box travels a distance $x$ during the flight time of the photon in the medium $t=Ln/c$ so that we have:

$$x=vt=v\frac{Ln}{c}=\frac{p}{M}\frac{Ln}{c}.\tag{3}$$

Putting $x$ from Eqn.$(3)$ into Eqn.$(1)$ we find

$$p=m\frac{c}{n}.\tag{4}$$

Now inside the medium light obeys the relations:
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\omega &=& \frac{c}{n}\ k,\tag{5}\\
\mathbf{p} &=& \hbar\ \mathbf{k},\\
E &=& \hbar\ \omega.
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Therefore inside the medium the momentum of a photon $p$ is related to its energy $E$ by the relation:
$$p=\frac{E\ n}{c}.\tag{6}$$

Combining Eqn.$(4)$ and Eqn.$(6)$ we find the following relation for the equivalent mass $m$ of a photon travelling in a medium of refractive index $n$:

$$m=n^2\frac{E}{c^2}.\tag{7}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: In general, you may want to check out the [Abraham–Minkowski controversy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham–Minkowski_controversy), in particular [Griffiths' letter on EM momentum](https://www.nucleares.unam.mx/~martinel/curso-ec19/griffiths_AJP_80_7.pdf) which treats similar examples.

Answer (score 3):

No, mass displaced will be always $\frac{E}{c^2}$, where $E$ is energy displaced. This is the fundamental principle, the medium with index of refraction $n \neq 1$ does not affect it.

Your argumentation mixes incompatible ideas and meanings of $n$.

First, you derive (4) for a scenario where EM energy pulse/wave packet moves through a medium with speed $c/n$ (let's work in classical theory for now). (There is a flaw in the idea that the whole box starts and stops moving immediately at the time of emission/absorption, but the result seems fine: in between the interactions, the box has momentum proportional to transported mass $m$ and some speed $c/n$, just as it would be if the mass and energy were transported by a massive body instead of EM pulse.)

However, letter $n$ here is not the index of refraction, but a divisor of $c$ that gives the correct decreased speed of energy transport in the medium. Index of refraction characterizes phase speed of a wave, not speed of energy transport. So a better way to write down the pulse momentum is
$$
p_{pulse} = m v_e
$$
where $v_e$ is the speed of energy transport in the medium. This should be, in the simple case far from resonance/absorption, equal or close to the group velocity, and should always be lower or equal to $c$:
$$
v_e \approx v_g = \frac{d\omega}{dk} = \frac{c}{n + \omega \frac{dn}{d\omega}}.
$$

Since transported mass is related to energy of the pulse $m = \frac{E_{pulse}}{c^2}$, we can relate momentum and energy of the pulse
$$
p_{pulse} = \frac{E_{pulse}}{c^2} v_e.
$$

Second, you derive (6) based on the quantum definition relations
$$
E = \hbar \omega,
$$
$$
p = \hbar k \tag{*}
$$
and the relation

$$
k =\frac{n\omega}{c}.
$$

Here $n$ is the standard index of refraction, and $E,p$ are energy and momentum ascribed to the quantum of radiation present in the medium. The radiation is assumed to have a meaningful $\omega,k$, so either the quantum is associated with a monochromatic wave, or with a wave packet centered around $\omega, k$ in the Fourier domain.

From this you get the relation between quantum energy and momentum

$$
p = \frac{E}{c^2}nc.
$$

Comparing this to the result for the classical pulse, we can say the quantum energy and momentum in the medium are prescribed in such a way (*) that energy in the pulse moves with velocity $nc$, which is usually greater than $c$. Nobody believes energy can move faster than $c$ in medium, so this should be interpreted as follows: our definition of quantum energy and momentum (*) does not allow for interpreting them as characteristics of a pulse of EM radiation energy. It's a formal definition.

A different way to say this is the relation $p =\hbar k$ gives the quantum more momentum in the medium $\hbar n\omega/c$ than it "should have" (to be compatible with the classical pulse idea). Trying to understand this quantum using a picture of energy pulse moving through the medium leads to energy having speed greater than $c$, which is wrong, so such a picture of the quantum is invalid.

If we want the quantum energy and momentum to be compatible with the idea of pulse of energy moving through the medium, we can speculate that the quantum should be ascribed different, lower momentum

$$
p = \frac{v_e}{nc}\hbar k.
$$

This way, we obtain the desired relation

$$
p = \frac{E}{c^2}v_e
$$

even for the quantum.

However, this is really a naive unreliable high-school-level analysis, and the "resolution" at the end is not orthodox physics. More detailed studies (Abraham, Minkowski, and their successors) show that there are problems with defining EM momentum and EM angular momentum in medium satisfactorily. One aspect of this is that when wave packet moves in a medium, part of momentum and energy is carried by EM field, and part is carried also by the material medium, and we can't really study the two parts independently - they are always associated. Sometimes the matter energy and momentum is treated as if part of EM energy and momentum, using appropriate macroscopic definitions. Resolving how much energy and momentum is associated with EM field, and how much with matter motion, is not easy.